# Mirror a sprite with touchesBegan?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

Here is my current code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveByX:-200.0 y:0.0 duration:0.7];
    [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeRight withKey:@"changeside"];
}
```

When I tap the screen I want my current sprite to mirror itself. If there isn't a way to mirror it, is there a way to change the sprite when the screen is tapped?

Also, when you tap the screen again I want the sprite to go back to it's original position on the screen and be flipped to the original sprite. Should I use code similar to this to determine which way it should go? Thank you!

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (isRightSide) {
        //Change to sprite's position to the LEFT side 
    } else {
    //Change to sprite's position to the RIGHT side 
    }
   isRightSide = !isRightSide;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To horizontally mirror a SKSpriteNode's texture:

```
mySprite.xScale = -1.0;
```

To flip back and forth, in the `touchesBegan` use this code:

```
if(mySprite.xScale == -1.0)
{
    mySprite.xScale = 1.0;
} else {
    mySprite.xScale = -1.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly. :) Do you happen to know how to reverse it on the second tap?

Comment: On the second tap how would you make it go back to the original position? Would it be something like your code but change whether the sprite is mirrored or not to what his position is?

Comment: @Ryanc - I do not understand what you are asking. The above code simply mirrors the sprite and has nothing to do with its position.

Comment: In the above code when you tap the sprite moves to X-200.0, on the second tap is there any way to make it go back to it's original position on the screen?

Comment: @Ryanc - I would guess that your sprite's image is a large one. If there is some empty space on the sides, crop the image. If you still don't get the desired results, you will have to create a mirror image and replace the image (texture) of the sprite instead of flipping it on its x axis.